# Issues parsing a nested JSON with AngularJS

Tags: html, json, angularjs, rest

I have the following contoller in my app :

```
angular.module('myApp.controllers', []).
  controller('ClientesController', [ '$scope', '$rootScope', 'Clientes',
     function($scope, $rootScope, Clientes) {
        $rootScope.clientes;

        Clientes.query(function(response) {
          $rootScope.clientes = response;
  })
}]);
```

Which returns a JSON object with the following format :

```
 [{"idCliente":1,
   "nomeFantasia":"Flores",
   "razaoSocial":"Transportes Flores Ltda.",
   "contatosClientes": 
   [  
      {"idContatoCliente":1,
       "dddCelular":21,
       "email":"ljames@cavaliers.com"},
      {"idContatoCliente":2,
       "dddCelular":21,
       "email":"test@cavaliers.com"}
   ]
  }]
```

And a template which tries to parse the JSON with ng-repeat :

```
<tr ng-repeat="cliente in clientes | filter:searchText">
  <td>{{cliente.idCliente}}</td>
  <td>{{cliente.razaoSocial}}</td>
  <td>{{cliente.nomeFantasia}}</td>
  <td>{{cliente.contatosClientes.email}}</td>
  <td>
     <div class="right floated ui green icon buttons">
        <div class="ui button">Editar</i></div>
     </div>
  </td>
</tr>
```

The problem is that I can access the outer keys (idCliente,razaoSocial, etc) with the object.key sintaxe, but I can't access the inner keys (contatosClientes.email, for example) in the nested array.

I've tried many approaches and I am starting to think that is something wrong with my REST API, but before change all my backend code I would like to know if someone can help me with this issue.

Best regards,
Antonio Belloni

Comment: contatosClientes is an array, you'll have to do ng-repeat for that too

Answer (score 5, accepted):

contatosClientes is an array, you'll have to do ng-repeat for that too, for example:

```
<tr ng-repeat="cliente in clientes | filter:searchText">
  <td>{{cliente.idCliente}}</td>
  <td>{{cliente.razaoSocial}}</td>
  <td>{{cliente.nomeFantasia}}</td>
  <td ng-repeat="contato in cliente.contatosClientes>{{contato.email}}</td>
  <td>
     <div class="right floated ui green icon buttons">
        <div class="ui button">Editar</i></div>
     </div>
  </td>
</tr>
```